# Firefox pop up obscures the screen paritally in selenium test

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I ran my test in BrowserStack and here is an example outcome

[image]

How can I turn off this behaviour of Firefox in a selenium test via `DesiredCapabilities`?

I want to be able to drive this behaviour with settings instead of adding code for a specific browser.

Comment: Are you loading any profile through `Selenium`?

Comment: Do you mean a firefox profile?

Comment: Exactly! that's what I meant. And, I am wondering why would that happen. I run selenium tests everyday and never came across this situation

Comment: I run it on a service called 'Browserstack' and I think it always starts a clean environment. If I run the test locally I don't see it too.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how `Browserstack` works. Do you have the option of unchecking the checkboxes of sharing data mentioned in my answer?

Comment: BTW, I believe you also should update the question saying it's specific to Browserstack as well

Answer (score 1):

This prompt is related to **firefox health report**, you can disable it in as: **(in java)**

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("datareporting.healthreport.uploadEnabled", false);
profile.setPreference("datareporting.healthreport.service.enabled",
                false);
profile.setPreference("datareporting.healthreport.service.firstRun",
                false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: Nice answer dude. Can you provide me the doc of of those preference. I was looking for that couldn't find

Comment: @Saifur it was just one of the issues i got in my past projects so some google at that time made me to have this noted in my quick notes. There are lot of things like telemetry and location that firefox provides you can have a look at them too. For telemetry use `about:telemetry` in url, and for other about config entries [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries) could be useful..